# How to flatten a nested array in Dart?

Tags: arrays, dart, flatten

How do I flatten a nested array?

```
[
  {
    "page": 1,
    "items": [
      {
        "addresses": [
          "hello1",
          "hello2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "page": 2,
    "items": [
      3,
      {
        "addresses": [
          "hello3",
          "hello4"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "page": 3,
    "items": [
      3,
      4
    ]
  }
];
```

Desired output ist:

```
["hello1", "hello2", "hello3", "hello4"]
```

```
import 'dart:convert';

main() {
  const jsonString =
      '[{"page":1, "items": [{"addresses": ["hello1","hello2"]}]}, {"page":2, "items": [3, {"addresses": ["hello3","hello4"]}]}, {"page":3, "items": [3, 4]}]';
  final items = jsonDecode(jsonString) as List;
  final x = items.expand((p) => p["items"]).expand((p) => p["addresses"]);
  print(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have a list of maps that look like this:

```
{
  page: int,
  items: List<{
    addresses: List<String>
  }>
```

except sometimes the items are just numbers, you want to get all addresses on a single list, here is how I would do it:

```
List<String> result = [];

p.forEach((obj) {
  final objMap = obj as Map<String, dynamic>
  objMap['items'].forEach((item) {
    if (item is Map<String, dynamic>) {
      result.addAll(item['addresses'] as List<String>);
    }
  });
});
```

A bit clunky, I know, but I think it will do the trick